# Erro ao gerar uma lista com dart - Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

```
    List diariasRecuperadas = await _db.listDiarias();
    //print('Diaria no banco' + diariasRecuperadas.toString());

    List<Diarias> listaProvisoria;

    for (var item in diariasRecuperadas) {
      Diarias d = Diarias.MapToModel(item);
      listaProvisoria.add(d);
    }

    setState(() {
      listaDiarias = listaProvisoria;
    });

    listaProvisoria = null;
  }
```

[image: imagem contendo a declaracao da lista]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //recuperar contatos
    //recuperarDiarias();

    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: listaDiarias.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final Diarias obj = listaDiarias![index];
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(obj.local.toString()),
                    subtitle: Text(obj.value.toString()),
                  ),
                  
                );
              }),
        ),
      ],
```

[image: imagem mostrando o erro quando nao coloco interrogacao]

Porém, quando colo interregoçao mostra essa saida no debugconsole

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building:
Null check operator used on a null value
```

Comment: Fala, @NewSystemsUnlimited. Vi no seu perfil que você já é antigo no site. Então acredito que já deva ter uma noção de como funciona por aqui. Pela sua pergunta, deu para entender qual era a dúvida. Porém, para ter mais chance de obter respostas em perguntas futuras, sugiro não colocar print do código (imagem) e sim ele em formato texto. Isso facilita a pessoa que for responder de copiar seu código e conseguir te ajudar. Outra coisa, tente sempre fornecer o maior número de informações possíveis, e uma dúvida concreta. Qual a dúvida, qual erro deu, em qual linha e o que já tentou é importante.

Comment: @Naslausky. Para mim acho que só bastava dizer: *"...que `List<Diarias> listaProvisoria;` não foi inicializada e em `listaProvisoria.add(d);` é equivalente a `null.add(d);` ..."*  espero que o autor da pergunta veja seu esforço em melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pelas colocações tem bastante tempo qua não utilizo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `recuperarDiarias()` é assíncrono e demora um tempo para concluir. Nesse meio tempo, você precisa fornecer um valor padrão para `listaDiarias`. Isto é, enquanto a função não acaba, o que deve ter nessa lista?

A forma mais simples é fornecer como valor inicial uma lista vazia. Ou seja, no lugar disso:

```
List<Diarias>? listaDiarias;
```

Faça isso:

```
List<Diarias> listaDiarias = [];
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. funcionou perfeitamente. Apenas adicionei o ponto de exclamação nesta parte do código. `código`itemCount: listaDiarias!.length`código`.